# Access is denied in one folder but not in another

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, batch-file, batch-rename

I had a number of files that were downloaded from the internet and they were in `Folder A`.

I tried to run a `.bat` file on them to rename them, but on every single file I got the error `Access is denied`.

Then I checked their properties, and they were not read-only, but they were blocked like so: `This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer`.

Then, I tried moving them to a newly created folder, `Folder B`, and running the `.bat` file again, and ***magically***, it worked.

I'm ***almost sure*** that both `Folder A` and `Folder B` were identical, except for their names, and that these folders had nothing special. `Folder B` was created on the spot with the standard way, and I'm assuming `Folder A` was also normally created this way. `Folder A` was somewhere in the `Documents` directory and I placed `Folder B` on my desktop.

Why did this strange behavior happen and how do I prevent it from happening in the future?

(Edit: I deleted both of these folders, so I cannot go and check their properties now)

Comment: Is the Documents folder within the same USERID as the Desktop folder?  It appears to be a permission issue. You can try taking ownership of the denied folder.

Comment: @John It says I have full control

Comment: I suggest then to make a copy of this folder in a different location and then use that. There must be something about where it originally came from.